# How do I parse with LXML recursively in an elegant way?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

For example, consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
  <div id="element1">
    text1
  </div>
  <div id="element2">
    text2
  </div>
  <div id="element3">
    text3
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to parse different elements, which attributes are already known.

The way that I am doing it now:

```
index = len(tree.xpath('//div[@class="class1"]')
for i in range(0, index):
    print tree.xpath('//div[@class="class1"][i]/text()')
```

But it becomes kinda messy when it comes to longer xpaths.
Is there another way to do this?

edit-

for example,

`first_elem = tree.xpath('//div[@class="class1"]')[0]`

is it possible to do something like:

`first_elem.xpath()` which searches in `<div id="element1">` ?

edit-

found the weird way to do this in lxml:

```
for i in tree.xpath('//div[@class="class1"]'):
    str1 = html.tostring(i)
    tree = html.fromstring(str1)
    < do things here >
```

Comment: What is the expected output? `text1`, `text2` and `text3` ?

Comment: @falsetru Yes. I am trying to parse those texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xpath` seems to be wrong , when you do -

```
tree.xpath('//div[@class="class1"][i]/text()')
```

`i` does not get substituted inside automatically. In anycase, you do not need to do what you are doing , `tree.xpath` would return a list of all matching elements, you can simple use the xpath you want (even if it results in more than one element) , and then iterate over the result and print it. Example (or what you are trying to do) -

```
for i in tree.xpath('//div[@class="class1"]/div/text()'):
    print i
```

This should print the text from inside each `div` in the main div with attribute `class` as `class1` .

---

You do not even need that, if you know a way to uniquely identify the element (using attributes/indexing, etc) , you can directly use that, example , to get the text for `element1` , use -

```
for i in tree.xpath('//div[@id="element1"]/text()'):
    print i
```

---

Also, seems like your xml has lots of not needed newlines and whitespaces , you can strip them by calling `i.strip()` .

Comment: Thank you. What if that I want to make xpath search recursively like "search under every elements returned from `//div[starts-with(@id, 'element')]`"?

Comment: `//` is to search at any level below the element , `/` is to search at 1 level below the previous element, you can use -`//div[starts-with(@id, 'element')]//<what you want>` or `//div[starts-with(@id, 'element')]/<what you want at 1 level>` .

Comment: You should use some online tutorial for xpath, its easy to learn/understand

Answer (score 1):

You can use `starts-with` to get `div` where `id` starts with `element`

```
for i in tree.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'element')]/text()"):
    print(i.strip())
```

and this yields

```
text1
text2
text3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all Childs of a element, i recommend to use `iter()`:

```
for element in tree.iter():
    print element.text.strip()
```

output:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

you can also define a tagname `tree.iter(tag="div")`